# Select full row on a DevExpress GridView depending on TextBox value

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, devexpress, vb.net-2010

How do I select the full row on a `DevExpress` `GridView` depending on `TextBox` value?

I tried the following code, but it's not working:

```
Dim rowHandle As Integer = GridView1.LocateByDisplayText(0, colC_Id, txtSelect.Text)
If rowHandle <> DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.InvalidRowHandle Then
    Dim row As System.Data.DataRow = GridView1.GetDataRow(GridView1.FocusedRowHandle)
    row(0) = txtSelect.EditValue
End If
```

Comment: Can you please format your code by placing each command on a separate line and indenting by 4 spaces. Can you be clearer about what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is. My understanding is that you have a DevExpress GridControl and you wish to select the the first row that matches the text entered into a text box on the same form. Is this correct? If so, is an exception being thrown or is a row not being selected when you expect it to be?

Comment: yes, but the row will not being selected. The textbox is being on the same user-control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code doesn't select a row in the GridControl. It does a case-sensitive search for the text entered in the text box in the GridColumn colC_Id and if a match is found, the text in the second column (column index 1) of the GridControl's data source is updated to the entered text in the row that is currently selected. The updated value will be reflected in the GridControl if that field from the data source has been added to the GridControl's GridColumn collection.

Here is an example of how to select a row in the GridControl based on a certain value where the GridControl's data source is a DataTable:

```
Dim myDataTable As DataTable = DirectCast(GridControl1.DataSource, DataTable)
Dim sFieldName As String = colC_Id.FieldName 
Dim sColumnName As String = colC_Id.Name
Dim myDataRows As DataRow() = myDataTable.Select(sFieldName & "='" & TextBox1.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'")

If myDataRows.Length > 0 Then
    Dim iDataSourceRowIndex As Int32 = myDataTable.IndexOf(myDataRows(0))
    GridView1.FocusedRowHandle = GridView1.GetRowHandle(iDataSourceRowIndex)
Else
    MessageBox.Show("The text '" & TextBox1.Text & "' was not found in column '" & sColumnName &"'")
End If
```